# Youtube channel livestream embedded doesn't work

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api, youtube-channels

I'm using iframe for embed youtube channel in my site, but it shows "An error ocurred. Please try again.". Strangely, if I set another channel ID it works.

[The channel ID that doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHns6.png)

[The channel ID that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAQHb.png)

I copied the debug information just in case:

```
{
  "cpn": "hWjSQIlGKWCb1Abv",
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "NaN",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "0",
  "vns": "0",
  "vec": "null",
  "vvol": "1",
  "creationTime": 65805,
  "totalVideoFrames": 0,
  "droppedVideoFrames": 0,
  "corruptedVideoFrames": 0,
  "state": "80",
  "debug_error": {
    "errorCode": "api.invalidparam",
    "errorDetail": "invalidVideodata.1",
    "message": "Se ha producido un error. Vuelve a intentarlo más tarde.",
    "messageKey": "GENERIC_WITHOUT_LINK",
    "subreason": ""
  },
  "relative_loudness": "NaN",
  "user_qual": "auto",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "Intel_Iris_Pro_OpenGL_Engine",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "unknown",
  "debug_date": "Fri Nov 16 2018 14:20:11 GMT-0400 (hora de Bolivia)"
}
```

And this is the code I used:

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  videoId: 'live_stream',
  playerVars: {
    channel: 'UCJC7T__QoftT5B3QkLUv7pQ',
    controls: 0,
    disablekb: 1,
    fs: 0,
    modestbranding: 1,
    rel: 0,
    showinfo: 0
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
```

Please, help me.

Comment: I'm also seeing similar errors.

Comment: Is there a solution? I enabled monetization but no luck

Comment: Instead of using the channel for embedding (`<iframe width="x" height="y" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel={channel_id}"></iframe>`) I finally use the format for single stream (`<iframe width="x" height="y"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video_id}"></iframe>`) and it worked, but I need to change the video_id every time I want to do a livestream.