# Embedded YouTube stream player error codes

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I can't find any documentation or useful search result. There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343771/youtube-channel-livestream-embedded-doesnt-work) mention this but no answer.

I'm getting "GENERIC_WITHOUT_LINK" error from live stream link (https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CORRECTCHANNELID). What cause this? I even enabled monetization. No luck. embed/livestream link won't work for my channel.

What cause this? Where can I get support?

Comment: did you check if your Channel ID is correct ? you can do it here https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced

Comment: Yes. I even tried use user ID and custom channel url key

Comment: did you configured correctly your stream ? and are you streaming while testing it ?

Comment: Yes, I am testing while streaming. What kind of configuration I need? It is pretty easy to go live stream on youtube. I only select "public" stream.